# as.Date not preserving hour and min information in R

Tags: r, date, posixct

I read in a csv to a data frame as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("Prices.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(data$Timestamp, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

I tried to use the below but the hour and min data was removed which is my question.  How can this be used with as.Date but preserving all info?

```
data$Timestamp <- as.Date(data$Timestamp, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

This is what data$Timestamp looks like using the as.POSIXct command above which is fine:

```
head(data$Timestamp)
[1] "2013-11-01 09:31:00 EDT" "2013-11-01 09:32:00 EDT" "2013-11-01 09:34:00 EDT" "2013-11-01 09:35:00 EDT"
[5] "2013-11-01 09:36:00 EDT" "2013-11-01 09:37:00 EDT"
```

This is a few data points from the original csv file:

```
Timestamp
11/1/13 9:31
11/1/13 9:32
11/1/13 9:34
11/1/13 9:35
11/1/13 9:36
11/1/13 9:37
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you converting to a `Date` if you want hour and minute information?

Answer (score 9):

You want a **Datetime class** such as `POSIXct` (or the expanded form `POSIXlt`), and not Date. See `help(DateTimeClasses)`.

Saying that `Date` discards hours and minutes is equivalent to saying that integers discard the part after the decimal -- that is the point. [ In fact, dates are often represented as integers but that is different here too as it really is fractional days, but I digress. ]

In a nutshell, if you do not have intra-day information, use `Date`. In all other cases, use `POSIXct`.

Comment: "Saying that Date discards hours and minutes is equivalent to saying that integers discards the part after the decimal" - Easy as that.  Thank you Dirk.  In my mind I remember using Date with hours and min data but looking back now at that script it was only the dates, no hours or min.