# How do you change a vector from CHR to INT in R?

Tags: r, vector, time, integer, chr

New user of R here so forgive my ignorance but I've hit a bit of a bind!

I am currently working on a data set called **Q1** which has a column for **Start_Time** that is displaying HH:MM except its vector is CHR and not INT or NUM.

I am currently trying to convert it to an INT or NUM so that I may change its format to HH:MM:SS but am having trouble doing so.

For Example:

```
Date <- c("11/22/22", "11/23/22", "11/24/22", "11/25/22")
Start_Time <- c("12:30", "14:25", "09:45", "17:50")
Q1 <- data.frame(Date, Start_Time)
```

So far I have tried

```
 strptime(Q1$Start_Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

 as.integer(Q1$Start_Time)

 Q1 <- transform(Q1, Start_Time = as.integer(Start_Time))

 Q1 <- transform(Q1, Start_Time = as.numeric(Start_Time))
```

But all of these have returned a value of NA through my whole column or given me an error about NAs introduced by coercion.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into an minimal reproducible example to make it easier for others to help?

Comment: ... for example if you can edit your question with the results of `dput(Q1$Start_Time[1:5])` please

Comment: You could try `sapply(strsplit(Q1$Start_Time, ":"), function(x) 60 * x[1] + x[2])` to get the time as an integer number of minutes.

Comment: Or `strptime(paste(Q1$Date, Q1$Start_Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")` to convert to proper date-time format

Comment: @AllanCameron This produced the error "Error in 60 * x[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator" the second one produced an NA response

Comment: check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324802/r-how-to-convert-a-character-to-a-numeric-value-without-creating-nas-or-nans-wh/72325182#72325182)

Comment: @onyambu funny enough, I think the person in that question is using the same Case Study as me although its a different dataset. Unfortunately the as.numeric(data.table::as.ITime(Q1$Start_Time)) formula that I used still returned an NA

Comment: I just ran `as.numeric(data.table::as.ITime(Q1$Start_Time))` and got `[1] 45000 51900 35100 64200` No `NA` values

Comment: Sorry, that should be `sapply(strsplit(Q1$Start_Time, ":"), function(x) 60 * as.numeric(x[1]) + as.numeric(x[2]))`

Comment: sorry @onyambu I just retried it in my dataset and it worked! You're a life saver thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as user @onyambu pointed out this question was answered by them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324802/r-how-to-convert-a-character-to-a-numeric-value-without-creating-nas-or-nans-wh/72325182#72325182)

But to also sum it up using as.ITime from the data.table worked perfectly

```
as.numeric(data.table::as.ITime(Q1$Start_Time))
```

and returned the values for

```
45000 51900 35100 64200
```

For anyone curious about converting it back to a HH:MM:SS format I used mutate

```
Q1 <- Q1 %>% mutate(Start_Time = hms::hms(Start_Time))
```

Thanks to everyone who pitched in!

Comment: This should have been closed as a duplicate.So I'll do that bit of housecleaning now.